# Getting Debian style wpa_supplicant in Buildroot

Tags: wpa-supplicant, buildroot, wpa-cli

Currently it seems like the Buildroot package for `wpa_supplicant` does not include the Roaming Mode functionality that is available in the Debian package. How would I manually include this in my Buildroot OS?